# PHPUnit pulling in config file

Tags: php, phpunit

I have a PHPUnit class that I want to run for multiple user types, which have their own credentials. I have the credentials in separate files which I want to include when I run the test class.

I have used the following command to include a user configuration file

```
phpunit --bootstrap User1.php MyTests.php
```

but unless I make the user credentials array global (which is obviously something I do not want to do), I don't know how I can access it from within my test class.

How can I pass a variable defined in a file I am including, into the constructor of my test class?

Thanks!

Comment: Why don't you just make global constants?

Comment: Yeah I guess I that would work, thanks. Is there not any way to pass an object into a PHPUnit test class then?

Comment: Don't think so no. I have seen people use env vars as well as consts, but don't think phpunit provides a way to pass in vars

Comment: OK, thanks for your help.

Comment: why don't you access User1.php from the setUp method in the test ?